# How to append a string in table cells if and only if that table cell is not empty?

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>aaaa</td>
  <td>bbbb</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td> 
  <td>ccccc</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

For above table, how can i append a string "iString" to the cell data "aaaa", "bbbb" and "cccc". But not for the empty cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("table td").each(function()
    {
        if($.trim($(this).text()).length > 0)
        {
            alert("Got my td with text. appending some string");

            var text = $.trim($(this).text());
            text += "mystring";

            $(this).text(text);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ym2JJ/1/) example.

The `$("table td")` selector selects each `td` element of the table, and the `.each()` is an iterator function, which will execute the callback provided as its argument for each element that matches the selector, which are the `td` elements of the table. Inside the callback, `this` will refer to the `td` element. The -

`$(this).text().length`

portion is checking to see if the text inside that `td` element has a length greater than zero. If it is, then you've got a `td` element with a text. The -

`var text = $(this).text();`

line fetches that text from the `td` and assigns it to the `text` variable. The next line concatenates the specified string with this variable. Finally, the -

`$(this).text(text);`

line assigns the concatenated string as the `td` element's text.

**Edit**

I've added the `$.trim()` function around the string-length checking to remove the white-space characters. If you want to consider the white-spaces as characters, just remove it.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table td').each(function(){


   var val = $(this).html() ;

   if(val.length) {

     $(this).append("yor string");
   }


});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table td').each(function() {
    if($(this).text()) {
        $(this).append('X');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/JQe2N/

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("table td").each(function(){
     if($.trim($(this).html()) != '') //Remove whitespaces with $.trim
        $(this).append("iString");
  });
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
$('td').each(function(){
  if ($(this).text() != "") {
    $(this).append(iString);
  }
});
```

Comment: it is working fine but it is adding "iString" to null cells. I think i have to remove whitespaces. Thanks kinakuta

Comment: Ah, I assume you meant empty cells by null cells. Yes, if there is possibly whitespace in them, you would need to remove it for this particular check to work.